# What is the plural of Thaï?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, grammatical-number

I've looked up the word Thaï in many dictionaries. It seems that its plural form may be "the Thaï", in the same way as "the French", or "the Thaïs" like "the Israelis."
Which one is most used by native speakers in the UK and in the US?

Comment: I agree with the good answers below.  And note, unlike French and other languages, in English it is customarily spelled without an “umlaut” (diæresis) — Thai, not Thaï.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

["Thai" is both an adjective and a noun](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Thai).  As a noun, it can refer to a person from Thailand, in the same way you might say "American":

> That **Thai** has on an orange coat.

However, to avoid confusion, and to be more polite, it's better to use it as an adjective:

> That **Thai gentleman** has on an orange coat.

To add to this confusion, the plural/collective of "Thai" is also "Thai", or occasionally "Thais".

> The **Thai** are famous for their delicious cuisine.
>
> **Thais** are famous for their delicious cuisine.

Again, it may be more convenient to use "Thai" as an adjective:

> The **Thai people** are famous for their delicious cuisine.

Comment: Andrew, just like "Chinese" and "Japanese".

Comment: @AIQ  Mostly.  You would never say "Chineses" or "Japaneses", though.

Answer (score 0):

"Thai people" or "People from Thailand"

It is possible to use Thai as a noun to mean "a person from Thailand", but it sounds better as an adjective.  As a noun the plural would be Thais, but this is rarely used and should be avoided.

> Both the French and Thai people share a love of good food.